# The first man to do pattern

Tags: tense

Shakespeare was the first man to ever write in this style.

Shakespeare is the first man to ever have written in this style.

Shakespeare is the first man to ever write in this style.

Shakespeare was the first man to ever have written in this style.

Which one(s) is wrong?

Comment: .......was the first man to write in this style.

Comment: All of these could be correct, it depends on context -- what you are trying to say.  If this is from a test, then it's not a very good test.

Comment: I wanted to say, "Shakespeare was the first person who wrote in this style." So what you are saying is that to impart this meaning, any of the above is correct?

Comment: @Andrew please see above

Comment: @user205376 no, not all the sentences are the same.  The past perfect changes the meaning slightly, and the context will change whether you say "Shakespeare **is**" or "Shakespeare **was**"  He's been dead 400 years so in many cases we would say **was**, but to some people he still lives in his works, and might prefer to say **is** when talking about the things he wrote.  Again, it depends on *exactly* what you want to say.

Comment: What about the last one? @Andrew

Comment: @user205376 as I said, all the sentences look grammatical to me.  That doesn't mean they all are *good writing* but you have yet to tell me what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

Better stylistically is not to split the infinitive:

> Shakespeare was the first man ever to write in this style.
>   Shakespeare was the first man ever to have written in this style.

Note that *write* is a bit better *stylistically* than *have written* there because it's shorter and a less complicated expression. But you could use *have written* there as well, though I am hard put to think of a case where that would be preferable.

Comment: "... ever to have written in this style *before [some other writer]*", maybe?  Although a good editor would still cross it out with his red pencil and put down "write" instead.  Simple past is better.